# Why does this card say DDR1 and DDR2, when only DDR1 fits?

Tags: memory, ddr

My motherboard says "DDR1 DDR2" next to the two RAM stick holders. The two holders are identical, and seem only to fit DDR1, though.

Does it simply mean "DDR holder #1" and "DDR holder #2"? Because I'd really like to fit a DDR2 stick in there.

Here is a picture:

[image: picture]

Comment: I read it as "slot 1" and "slot 2". If only DDR1 fits then it's highly likely it was still just called "DDR memory" at the time the board was made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct in your assertion that they are simply identifiers for the RAM slots. It is not possible to have 2 differing RAM types on a single board.

Comment: Exactly.............. +1 for that

Comment: Motherboards that support two different RAM types are rare (and that's not what's happening here), but they *do* exist: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kmnGW.jpg), [article](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/MSi-Eight-Memory-Slots,7214.html)

Comment: Interesting, i wasn't aware of that. It seems you're right, there are a few boards that support DDR2 and DDR3.